# ubuntu: upgrading software (cmake) - version disambiguation (local compile)

Tags: linux, cmake, version, upgrade

I had cmake 2.8.0 installed on my machine (from ubuntu packages), the binary was placed in /usr/bin/cmake. I need to upgrade cmake version to at least 2.8.2. The ubuntu version is quite old, but I can't upgrade it right now, therefore I have to install it from sources. I've downloaded cmake 2.8.2, followed [instructions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/install.html), and made `make install` with root privileges. Now I've got two parallel cmakes installed on my machine:

- /usr/bin/cmake - 2.8.0
- /usr/local/bin/cmake - 2.8.2

```
any_user@machine $ cmake --version
2.8.0

root@machine $ cmake --version
2.8.2
```

What should I do to get rid of 2.8.0 (which is obsolete for me right now) or just to replace 2.8.0 with 2.8.2? I would like any non-user to type `cmake` (without specifying the path) to get newer version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cmake version that [Ubuntu ships](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cmake) is 2.8.9 which is even newer than the version you custom built...

Comment: Yes, but - as I wrote - I've got old ubuntu (lucid lynx) and I can't upgrade it right now. Ubuntu 10.04 (LL) is shipped with 2.8.0

Comment: My bad, I missed that part (although it is kind of 'hidden')

Comment: [Full answer on Ask Ubuntu (sister site)](http://askubuntu.com/q/829310/49899)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally one uses these steps (basically for any custom build application):

First, check if the newly build cmake seems to be working, by using it from its build location.

When you confirmed it is working, you properly remove the Ubuntu version using:

```
apt-get remove cmake
```

Finally, install the newer cmake using the `make install` command.

In our case, as you already installed the custom build version, you might want to reinstall cmake again after removing the Ubuntu package, to prevent cmake being broken due to the removing process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed it and now I've got cmake version 2.8.10.2 (latest one) inside /usr/local/bin and nothing in /usr/bin (after apt-get remove). Root user finds /usr/local/bin, but ordinary users return the following error when running `$ cmake` from command line 'bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory'. Should I run `make install` with another option.

Comment: In a proper setup the locations that are being searched (stored in the `PATH` variable) include `/usr/local/bin`, so it should work. Did you modify this environment variable?

Comment: the PATH was ok. logout and login and everything works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to install your package. It creates a package you can install on your system. This way the files you install are handled by the package manager and can be removed easily.
I think the old package will be removed automatically, when you give the package you create a newer version (I'm not sure here).